# Transfer time into mySQL database, defined as "Thu, 14 Apr 2011 22:44:33 +0000" gives me syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, phpmyadmin

I have the options of using regular expressions and substr() to parse out the data, but I am looking to pass the data as is to a date, datetime or timestamp column if possible. I prefer not to strip anything out. I am building a new database from a commercial sites API, to be used for data management. I have tried to input as char and varchar with similar error.
I have looked at the As defined: option in phpMyAdmin and attempted to 'define' the data as

```
%a, %y %b %Y %H:%i:%s
```

while pulling the +0000 with a substr() function, no luck.

Comment: mysql's standard easiest-to-use format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. no time zones, no fancy 'string' components.

Comment: @MarcB Is there a PHP function that can format to the yyyy-mm-dd from 14 Apr 20011? I was able to pass the other data, but then it does not sort, so your idea will be the best option.

Comment: cheap/quick: [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) + [date](http://php.net/date). better option: [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime)

Comment: That answers my question, thank you! I will have to spend more time on php.net.. very well documented.

Comment: This worked, $date_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($products->date_created));

Answer (score 1):

You can find the supported formats in [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

If you want to use MySQL to convert your date format, check out [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).